# Magento2 : getting 503 Service Unavailable error on change attribute set in product

Tags: magento-2.1, attribute-set

In my magento2.x store when I change attribute set then the post request return "503 Service Unavailable" error in console.

POST request is :

```
/catalog/product/reload/id/296/type/configurable/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/10/key/656ff14895b6b0084f246bd058fbcb5a779de375a493f9051af6d76262847785/?set=9&isAjax=true
```

And in "var/report" there is a report file with following error :

```
a:4:{i:0;s:49:"Invalid UI Component element name: 'product_form'";i:1;s:2874:"#0 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('product_form')
#1 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(125): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)
#2 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#3 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#4 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#8 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(935): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#9 /home/domain/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(37): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#10 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(181): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#11 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#12 /home/domain/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Layout/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#13 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 /home/domain/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#15 /home/domain/public_html/index.php(141): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:196:"/admin_o029x8/catalog/product/reload/id/296/type/configurable/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/10/key/656ff14895b6b0084f246bd058fbcb5a779de375a493f9051af6d76262847785/?set=9&isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same error.

I have done the following:

1. Find id of "Attribute Set" in database column eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id
2. UPDATE eav_entity_type SET default_attribute_set_id = '%YOUR_Attribute_Set_ID%' WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product';
3. Re-index and Clear cache

Reference : [Magento 2.2 - How to change default attribute set](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/211818/magento-2-2-how-to-change-default-attribute-set/211822#211822)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/117850)

Comment: I've updated my answer