# Magento 2.2 - How to change default attribute set

Tags: magento2.2, attribute-set

I have two attributes sets

1. Set1
2. Set2

While adding the product, By default Set1 is selected for Attribute Set.

I want this default Attribute set to be Set2.
How to change this attribute set.

Where to check set1 is defined as default attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find id of "Attribute Set" in database column eav_attribute_set.attribute_set_id
2. UPDATE `eav_entity_type` SET `default_attribute_set_id` = '%YOUR_Attribute_Set_ID%' WHERE `eav_entity_type`.`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product';
3. Re-index and Clear cache

Comment: I have added product using default attribute set now I want to change the attribute set, so I have create a csv using sku and new attribute set but it didn't work, any idea?